# Angular keypress stores space instead of first letter

Tags: angular

I am having problem with Angular's (keypress). I want to store event.target.value as variable but if I write 'pizza' in the input field, it stores 'pizz'. How can I store the 'pizza' anyway?

Thanks for the help.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" (keypress)="onKeypressEvent($event)" />
```

Typescript:

```
  storedValue: string = '';

  onKeypressEvent(event: any) {
    console.log(event);
    console.log(event.target.value);
    this.storedValue = event.target.value;

    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
       this.onSubmit();
    }

  }
```

Working example on StackBlitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ddyqbx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

**SOLVED**

I added two way binding to my input field and it solved the problem.
Maybe this is not "the best" practice, but it solved the problem.

```
 <input type="text" (input)="keyValue(event)" (keypress)="onKeypressEvent($event)" />


  onKeypressEventOccupation(event: any) {
    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
      this.onSubmit();
    }
  }

  keyValue(event: any) {
    this.storedValue = event.target.value;
  }
```

Comment: use `(input)` event instead. or better yet two way binding. https://angular.io/guide/two-way-binding

Comment: Or change `(keypress)` to `(keyup)`

Comment: Thank you, I used (input) and it works great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as per doc , [keypress](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_event) will sent previous character of a character which you are pressing at moment. So that is reason you always see characters except most recent character in your `event.target.value`.

e.g. -> you typed `pizza` , `event.target.value` will have `pizz`.

As most recent character is yet to pressed down by any new input.

As mentioned in comments, you can use `keyup` or `input` for displaying all characters as soon as you typed it.